# How to store image file in Folder mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to store file name in the path but my model image file type is a string that's why to give error not define. When I use public httppostfilebase then file name not show in controller only when I use a string then file name show so follow the line of code not working when I use string i want to store file name. Any expert tells me how to resolve this issue.

Error: Problem with string data type.

C#

```
     [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult mQuotationInsert(int Qt_ID, string EnteryDate, string Purpose, Quotation[] Quot, string AddNew)
        {
            string result = "Error! Order Is Not Complete!";
            try
            {
                objQuotation.QuotationInsert(Qt_ID, EnteryDate, Purpose, Quot, AddNew);
                ModelState.Clear();
                result = "Quotation Inserted Successfully!";
                return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }

public int QuotationInsert(int Qt_ID, string EnteryDate, string Purpose, Quotation[] Quot, string AddNew)
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                tr = con.BeginTransaction();

                if (AddNew == "New")
                {

                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Right('00' + Cast(ISNULL(MAX(Qt_ID),0)+1  as varchar(2)) + '', 2) from QuotationMain", con);
                    cmd.Transaction = tr;
                    Qt_ID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_QuotationMainInsert", con);
                }
                else
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_QuotationMainUpdate", con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qt_ID", Qt_ID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comp_ID", 1);

                if (EnteryDate != null)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnteryDate", EnteryDate);
                else
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnteryDate", string.Empty);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", HttpContext.Current.Session["AgentName"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Purpose", Purpose);

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Transaction = tr;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();



                if(Quot !=null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Quot.Length; i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Quot[i].imageFile.FileName);
                            string extension = Path.GetExtension(Quot[i].imageFile.FileName);
                            fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + extension;
                            Quot[i].imagePath = "~/AppFiles/Images/" + fileName;
                            fileName = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/AppFiles/Images/"), fileName);
                            Quot[i].imageFile.SaveAs(fileName);


                            if (AddNew == "New")
                            {
                                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ISNULL(MAX(Qt_Dt_ID), 0) + 1 from QuotationDetail", con);
                                cmd.Transaction = tr;
                                mQt_Det_ID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());


                                cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_QuotationDetailInsert", con);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qt_Dt_ID", mQt_Det_ID);

                            }

                            else if (AddNew == "Edit")
                            {
                                cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_QuotationDetailUpdate", con);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qt_Dt_ID", Quot[i].Qt_Dt_ID);
                            }

                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qt_Dt_ID", mQt_Det_ID);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qt_ID", Qt_ID);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SrNo", Quot[i].Srno);

                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartyName", Quot[i].PartyName);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsMature", Quot[i].IsMature);

                            if (Quot[i].imagePath != null)
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", fileName);

                            cmd.Transaction = tr;
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {

                            throw;
                        }


                    }
                }



                tr.Commit();
                return i;
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlex)
            {
                tr.Rollback();
                throw sqlex;  // read all sql error 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tr.Rollback();
                throw ex; // General execption

            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Model

```
[NotMapped]
public string imageFile { get; set; }
```

javascript

```
 function saveQuotation(data) {

            if ($.trim($("#txtQtID").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#txtNEnteryDate").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#txtNPurpose").val()) == "") return;

            return $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Home/mQuotationInsert",
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error!")
                }
            });

        }


    $("#saveQuotation").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var QuotationArr = [];
        QuotationArr.length = 0;
        $.each($("#detailsTable tbody tr"), function () {

            QuotationArr.push({
                Srno: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html(),
                PartyName: $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html(),
                imageFile=$(this).find('td:eq(2)').html(),
                IsMature: $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html()
            });
        });

        var data = JSON.stringify({
            Qt_ID: parseInt($("#txtQtID").val()),
            EnteryDate: $("#txtNEnteryDate").val(),
            Purpose: $("#txtNPurpose").val(),
            Quot: QuotationArr,
            AddNew: $("#AddNew").val()
        });

        $.when(saveQuotation(data)).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }).fail(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

Comment: `imageFile= Quot[i].imageFile.FileName` is this what you want?

Comment: Yes in this imageFile store the name of image . @ Prashant Pimpale

Comment: This line show error Filename because model property string type .

Comment: when i use httppostfilebase then name not show in imagefile show null value .

Comment: `imageFile= Quot[i].imageFile.FileName.toString();`

Comment: So --> You want to store the fileName of HttpPosted file in the string variable?

Comment: `Quot[i].imageFile.FileName` => is this throwing `NullReferenceException`? Also you need to provide `HttpPostedFileBase` property & related information.

Comment: not working : show this error filename does not contain a definition of filename and no extension method filename accepting first argument .@Prashant Pimpale

Comment: @ Tetsuya Yamamoto i ll share c# and javascript code then kindly review my code where i am wrong.

Comment: i have shared whole code @Tetsuya Yamamoto you can see

Comment: i have shared whole code @Prashant Pimpale you can see.  My name is in string variable and i want to store in folder .

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto due string i cannot use this line of code string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Quot[i].imageFile.FileName); Quot[i].imageFile.SaveAs(fileName); and show error

Comment: @ershoaib  i need your help .